# Json: Print values of a certain key

Tags: javascript

I have read similar questions but they don't use very extensive json examples and I haven't been able to figure this out after hours of trial and error.

So I have the following (partial) `Json` structure: (I put in random data)

```
{
    "name": "Game1",
    "children": [
    {
        "name": "World1",
        "children": [
        {
            "name": "Level1",
            "children": [
            {
                "name": "Part1",
                "size": 3938,
                "enemies" : [
                    ["Goomba",1000],
                    ["Mushroom",500]
                ]
            }
            ]
        }
        ]
    }
    ]
}
```

**Of course there are many Games, Worlds, etc.**
This means every `Level` will have many `Part`'s. The Location of the `Part` I am looking for is random or even absent in different `Levels`. 
How can go through this structure and for every instance of , for example, `Part3` print "Part3" and "enemies:[["name",number]["name",number]]"?
Where The parts aren't neccecarily numbered (so without using the index `[2]`.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: There's not a single instance of Part3 in your json

Comment: There is no `Part3`?

Comment: @DarrenSweeney "Of course there are many Games, Worlds, etc." Imagine there being 1 game, 10 Worlds, 100 parts etc

Comment: Let me rephrase... `There is no Part3`? Is this a typo? Did you mean `Part1`? We don't assume anything, please be explicit

Comment: I did not mean `Part1.` I meant `Part3`. Every `Level` will have many `Part`'s. The Location of the `Part` I am looking for is random or even absent in different `Levels`. I will update the question.

Comment: So, from your sample data, what would be the desired result? What do you want to print?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty sure the only way to accomplish what you want is to recursively visit every node in your JSON document, checking if it matches your criteria. You may find Object.keys helpful.

Something like this:

```
function forEachNodeInJSONDoc(jsonDoc, callbackFn, pathArray) {
   const rootPathArray = pathArray ? pathArray.slice() : [];
   Object.keys(jsonDoc).forEach(function(key) {
       var childPath = rootPathArray.slice();
       childPath.push(key);
       callbackFn(jsonDoc[key], childPath);
       forEachNodeInJSONDoc(jsonDoc[key], callbackFn, childPath);
   });
}
```

That would call your callback function for each node in the document, at which point you can check if the value matches your criteria.

This can be used like so, for example, to find all nodes that have the name "level3":

```
var nodesByPathMatchingLevel3 = {};
function matchesLevel3(node, path) {
   if(node.name === "level3") {
      nodesByPathMatchingLevel3[path.join(':')] = node;
   }
}
forEachNodeInJSONDoc(myJSON, matchesLevel3);
// Nodes by path now contains a key for each path (eg "1:2:5") that had the name level3 with the actual node as the value
```

Comment: I am so sorry for asking but I am `really` short on time, how would I check if it matches the criteria?

Comment: So your callback function would be doing the heavy lifting there. It will be called for each part of your document. In that callback you would just check if jsonDoc.name matches what you want.

Comment: I updated my answer to hopefully address your question a bit more directly.

Comment: My excuses for the late reply, with your help I managed to figure it out and promptly fell asleep. The custom example is really appreciated!

Comment: You're very welcome! Happy to hear you got it working :)